# Using the start timestamp in a RollingFile

Tags: log4j2

I have the following RollingFileAppender setup:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile">
    <FileName>${LOG_DIR}system.log</FileName>
    <FilePattern>${LOG_DIR}system%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss}.log.zip</FilePattern>
    <JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" />
    <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
    </Policies>
    <!-- roll over strategy, with unlimited files created -->
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax" />
</RollingFile>
```

It does nearly exactly what i want (new log file at midnight or on startup/restart), but unfortunately the timestamps that get assigned to the rolled over log files are sometimes simply incorrect. So for example:

```
system.log // current log, started at 2022-08-10 at midnight
system2022-08-09 00.00.00.log.zip // started at 2022-08-09 at midnight, so this is fine
system2022-08-08 00.00.00.log.zip // started at 2022-08-08 10.09 am, so this is not fine
system2022-08-08 10.04.57.log.zip // started at 2022-08-08 at 8.55 am, so this is not fine
```

As you can see `system2022-08-08 00.00.00.log.zip` is using a completely wrong timestamp and `system2022-08-08 10.04.57.log.zip` is using the timestamp when the log ended.

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Appreciate any suggestions on how to properly combine `OnStartupTriggeringPolicy` and `CronTriggeringPolicy` to achieve my goal here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this behavior is unfortunately a bug in log4j2, and an old one. See my comment here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2148

I also posted a solution for log4j2 2.18.0 in there, which will atleast does what i desire - there are still several things wrong in log4j2 itself though.